# Many-to-one tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

We've just retagged 88 question from `[internet]` `[explorer]` to `[internet-explorer]` and I think this isn't the most efficient way to deal with these kind of 'mistakes'. Shouldn't it be possible to automatically convert those two separate tags to one, as in setting the former two as synonymous to the latter one?

The same appears to be true to `[java]` + `[script]` → `[javascript]`, but not in every case: e.g., I just went along [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023533) which is really about Java. I don't want to cram these sites with dialogues, but isn't some kind of warning message when posting a question with these two tags appropriate?